# Disable primary menu link in drupal 6 without using any drupal module?

Tags: menu, drupal-6

I am using drupal 6. in My project i have used primary menu's but from them i want disable one primary menu link. For that i don't want to any special module. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- admin/build/menu-customize/primary-links - > You can uncheck the
  `enabled` check-box to just disable the primary link
- In css, you    could just disable the primary link with
  `visibility:hidden` or    `display:none`